# Django: Naive datetime on query

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to retrieve all data between two dates (monday -> monday). Here's my code:

```
    some_day_last_week = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    monday_of_last_week = some_day_last_week - timedelta(days=(some_day_last_week.isocalendar()[2] - 1))
    monday_of_this_week = monday_of_last_week + timedelta(days=7)

    print "Someday last week %s" % some_day_last_week
    print "Monday of last week %s" % monday_of_last_week
    print "Monday of this week %s" % monday_of_this_week
    jobs = Jobs.objects.filter(created_time__gte=monday_of_last_week, created_time__lt=monday_of_this_week).order_by('-created_time')

    for job in jobs:
        print "Jobb: %s (%s)" % (job, job.created_time)
```

The output is fine, but I'm getting a RuntimeWarning which is bugging me. Here's that (as well as the other output):

```
Someday last week 2013-03-14 15:11:32.819508
Monday of last week 2013-03-11 15:11:32.819508
Monday of this week 2013-03-18 15:11:32.819508
xxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-03-11 15:11:32.819508) while time zone support is active.
```

RuntimeWarning)
    xxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-03-18 15:11:32.819508) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
    Jobb: Webdesigner (2013-03-13 09:14:02+00:00)
    [21/Mar/2013 15:11:32] "GET /jobs/feed/7days/ HTTP/1.1" 200 712

I have USE_TZ set to True in settings.py, and the field created_time is like this:

```
created_time = models.DateTimeField(_('Creation time'), default=datetime.now)
```

Anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jobs = Jobs.objects.filter(
    created_time__range[monday_of_last_week, monday_of_this_week]).order_by('-created_time')
```

Comment: global name 'created_time__range' is not defined. Shouldn't __range work out of the box? :)

Comment: Ah, you missed an =. But still, I get the same runtime warning.. :/

Comment: try `monday_of_last_week.date` and `monday_of_this_week.date`

Comment: Then I get: [u'\xab<built-in method date of datetime.datetime object at 0x10b329fd0>\xbb-value has an invalid date format. The m\xe5 v\xe6re p\xe5 value YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ].']

Comment: you got that error because your value contains time. It should be date only.

Comment: Oh sorry, I use dot instead of __. `monday_of_last_week__date` and `monday_of_this_week__date`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26651/discussion-between-mats-and-catherine)